# Updating email domain name in Rails Console for many users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a User model where there is an email address with user@domain.com

What I'd like to do is to be able to update all the users in the system to change their domain name from @domain.com to @newdomain.com

Is there some way I can run a command (update_all) or something like that which would look for just the end portion (@domain.com) and change it for all records to @newdomain.com?

If I have to do it one by one via the console or Rails_Admin I will, just hoped there was a way to do this programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may iterate on all your users and update the address with `gsub`, like:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.email = user.email.gsub('@domain.com', '@newdomain.com')
  user.save!
end
```

Or, if the number of users is really big, you should do it directly in the database, with one update query. This depends on the database system, in Postgres it would look like:

```
update users set email = replace(email, '@domain.com', '@newdomain.com');
commit;
```

Comment: You could do it in one line, but the syntax if slightly different: `User.all.each {|user| user.email = user.email.gsub('@domain.com', '@newdomain.com'); user.save! }`

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I figured.  I need to get more friendly with the console.  I usually use it for simple stuff, not tasks like this.  I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Just iterate over all users with matching email addresses in batches and update their email's domain with the new domain name:

```
User.where("email LIKE '%@domain.com'").find_each do |user|
  user.update_attributes(
    email: user.email.sub('@domain.com', '@newdomain.com')
  )
end
```

Comment: I tried doing this from the Rails console, matching up my model and email field names and when I hit enter the console returns nothing.  And yes, I'm including an end statement :)  Any thoughts?